# AttributeError: module 'carts.views' has no attribute 'add'

Tags: html, python, django

Cuando intento arrancar el servidor de django con python aparece lo siguiente:

```
AttributeError: module 'carts.views' has no attribute 'add'
```

Aparecio de un momento a otro sin apenas haber tocado nada. A continuacion dejo mas detalles.
views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponseBadRequest
from .models import Cart
from products.models import Product
from .funciones import funcionCarrito

def cart(request):
    cart = funcionCarrito(request)


def add(request, product_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            # Obtener el producto a partir de su ID
            product = Product.objects.get(pk=product_id)
        
            # Obtener el carrito del usuario
            cart = Cart.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
        
            # Agregar el producto al carrito
            cart.products.add(product)
        
            # Redireccionar a la página del carrito
            return redirect('cart')  # Ajusta el nombre de la vista de acuerdo a tu configuración
        
    except Product.DoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponseBadRequest("El producto no existe.")

return HttpResponseBadRequest("Método de solicitud no válido.")
```

Según el mensaje de error en la consola la linea de codigo del archivo urls.py que falla es la siguiente:  `urlpatterns = [ path('cart/add/<int:product_id>/', views.add, name='add'),`

Comment: intento agregar mi archivo urls pero la pagina no me deja añadirlo

Comment: Para dar formato a tu código, agrega triples acentos graves (```) una línea antes y una después del mismo. La comunidad no puede editar tu pregunta para modificar el formato ya que en Python la indentación es crítica, por lo tanto queda a tu cargo corregirla.

Comment: gracias @padaleiana ya he editado la pregunta con la linea de codigo donde supuestamente esta el error.